# XPATH query: possibility of using "*" inside string

Tags: google-sheets, xpath-2.0

I use a `Xpath` `//div[@class='card details1']`. This works.

Could I use `//div[@class='card details*']` so that all classes with card details `1,2` inside `div`  to whatever comes back?

When I tried it it didn't work. Is there a way for me to use this wildcard * inside `xpath` itself, without any external programming?

Comment: Yes, wildcards can be used in some importxml. Share your complete path and we can try it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a way to Use XPATH : `"starts-with(@class,'card details')"` Can also use `contains`